# Temporarily storing and re-setting a property value in C#

Tags: c#

When I'm writing tests in a specific code base, I often need set a static **property** before my newly added code, and re-set it back when leaving. Example

```
public void SomeMethod(){
    val oldVal = Notifier.DoNotify;
    Notifier.DoNotify = false;

    // Some code...

    Notifier.DoNotify = oldVal;
}
```

I think this way is ugly and I want something nicer and which also makes it harder forget to re-set the value.

I tried cooking something up and got this. I see some benefits, but it's a pretty talky solution.

```
public class ValueHolder<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action<T> setter;
    private readonly T oldVal;

    public ValueHolder(Func<T> getter, T tempVal, Action<T> setter)
    {
        this.setter = setter;
        oldVal = getter();
        setter(tempVal);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         setter(oldVal);
    }
}
```

Which then is used like

```
public void SomeMethod(){
    using(new ValueHolder<bool>(() => Notifier.DoNotify, false, (b) => Notifier.DoNotify(b)) {

        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

What is a good solution to this?

(**Edit** removed reference to testing. Seemed to distract from what I wanted to ask)

Comment: You better hope your tests don't run in parallel...

Comment: Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate site for such questions

Comment: What testing framework are you using? There is often a way to have some code run before and after the test method.

Comment: It certainly looks better than manually resetting the value. I'd change the name of the class to focus on its resetting behavior though.

Comment: Thanks for comments! Although I'm not looking for how to use the test framework to work around the problem. I'm well versed in unit-testing, but right now more interested in learning C#

Comment: Is it necessary to use a lambda to get the existing value? Why not just pass that value in directly?

Comment: Ben, no you're right. It is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things you can do to make it a little easier to write. I would try to leverage whatever testing framework you are using to help running some setup/cleanup code before and after the test. But barring that here some tips that can cut down on the boiler plate.

First we can create a helper class that will cut down a little on the boilerplate for creating a `ValueHolder<T>` instance. I'll use LINQ Expressions to create the getter and setter delegates automatically rather than requiring the caller pass in both a getter and setter (although that could still be useful in advanced cases).

```
public class ValueHolder
{
    public static ValueHolder<T> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T>> staticProp, T tempVal)
    {
        var ex = (MemberExpression)staticProp.Body;
        var prop = (PropertyInfo)ex.Member;
        var getter = (Func<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>), prop.GetGetMethod());
        var setter = (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), prop.GetSetMethod());
        return new ValueHolder<T>(getter, tempVal, setter);
    }
}
```

This makes the creation a little more terse

```
ValueHolder.Create(() => Notify.DoNotify, false);
```

Second, you will probably need to set a few of these and a big using is kind of ugly. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218822/517852) to this question provides a way to handle this scenario in a slightly easier way using a class that inherits from `List<T>` which is also `IDisposable`. Combining these you could make your setup much simpler:

```
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    // before any state has change.

    using (Setup())
    {
          // Test code.
    }

    // the cleanup code has run so the state is reset here.
}

private static IDisposable Setup()
{
    return new DisposableList() {
        ValueHolder.Create(() => Notify.DoNotify, false),
        ValueHolder.Create(() => ConnectionManager.MaxConnections, 100),
        ValueHolder.Create(() => SomeClass.SomeProp, 2.5),
        // etc., I think you get the idea.
    };
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the list.
Using Linq seems kind of expensive?

Comment: @Peteter Expression trees and reflection are more expensive than lambdas, but I doubt it is a significant amount of time. On the order of hundreds of nanoseconds instead of tens. You aren't going to notice that unless you have some pretty strict performance requirements for your tests.

Comment: Thanks! You're probably right. (Performance is always important - I care about the battery life of my user's laptops. I've removed the reference to testing :-) Still, even for testing I care about performance.)