# Finally block executing before catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

As far as I understand try-catch-finally statement, just after exception is caught finally block gets executed. How does this apply when function throws exception, like example below. What if some resources are released in finally block which by initial exception could not be. Does this mean that finally block throws new (another) exception, overriding original exception.

I know that you can catch the exception that might be thrown in the try block of a try-finally statement higher up the call stack. That is, you can catch the exception in the method that calls the method that contains the try-finally statement ([msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)).

```
static void foo()   
{
  try   
  {
    Console.WriteLine("foo");
    throw new Exception("exception");   
  }   
  finally   
  {
    Console.WriteLine("foo's finally called");   
  }   
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    foo();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
foo
foo's finally called
Exception caught
```

Comment: the try & finally statement is embedded within the try of the main method

Comment: `finally` gets executed no matter you throw exception before it.

Comment: Related: [What Happens In C# If A Finally Block Throws An Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2911215/335858)

Answer (score 11):

> As far as I understand try-catch-finally statement, just after
>   exception is caught finally block gets executed.

No, that's wrong.

The `finally` block gets executed after either an applicable `catch` clause block has been executed, or immediately after the exception is thrown if no applicable `catch` exists. However, that only applies to `catch` and `finally` on the same `try` block -- if the exception is propagated, `finally` will run before any `catch` and/or `finally` that is further up the call stack.

> How does this apply when function throws exception, like example
>   below.

`foo` is called, it throws, and its `finally` block is executed. Since there was no `catch` the exception propagates and is caught inside `main`.

> What if some resources are released in finally block which by initial
>   exception could not be.

I do not understand the question.

> Does this mean that finally block throws new (another) exception,
>   overriding original exception.

Yes, [that's how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2911215/50079).

Comment: Also, to comment on _Does this mean that finally block throws new (another) exception, overriding original exception._ Yes, the finally exception will override the (original) first exception.

Comment: @TheDutchMan: Thanks, I have expanded on the answer and included that information as well.

Answer (score 2):

this is basically what you are trying to do:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   try
   {
       try   
       {
          Console.WriteLine("foo");
          throw new Exception("exception");   //error occurs here
       }   
       finally   //will execute this as it is the first exception statement
       {
           Console.WriteLine("foo's finally called");   
       }   
    }
    catch (Exception e)  // then this
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
    }
 }
```

I should also add that the code in the finally block is executed no matter what happens in the try and catch blocks

Answer (score 1):

When you are using try-catch-finally.
If your code get any error then it goes to first catch and then finally.
If your code does not threw any error then it will at last calls the finally and then further goes for execution.

[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154121/Using-Try-Catch-Finally) explains with good example.